# Advice when regarding pasting data into questions and can it be done in comments or just answers?

Tags: support

I think I may have partly solved my own query in the main forum (another person asked me to come back with a QQ plot in comments and the QQ plot suggests a normal distribution) and to find out if I have understood this (I don't have a great statistics background but I've done some research) I would like to paste the plot which I've put together in Excel straight into the question (1 answer with 11 follow-up comments).

Can data be pasted into a comment or do I have to answer my own question so that I can paste the data in?

Is there an easy way to do this? The reason why I ask is that I have copied spreadsheet data in to questions in the past I haven't got the formatting right and as a result it has been difficult to read the data. I have tried looking through the markdown editing help and have not really understood what I am supposed to do (but I am figuring that you can't just copy and paste in?). With regard to images (which essentially is what the chart/plot will be) can you paste these in directly if there is no link behind them (the advice implies that you need to add a ! in front and then a link?). I apologise for the basic nature of the question but I am just keen to do things appropriately.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 4):

1. Comments don't support much formatting.  Data and images will not work well with them.
2. It's probably best to post a reply to your own question.
3. Spreadsheet stuff comes with tabs and extra spaces that confound the markup here.  One solution is to paste from the spreadsheet into a word processor, convert all tabs to spaces, and then paste that into a reply.
4. It believe you need a higher reputation to post images.  As a workaround you can upload an image on the Web and include a link to it in your post.  A higher-rep user will likely come along to turn that link into an embedded image.

Comment: thanks for this it is immensely helpful. 1&2 - I kind of figured but wanted to ask to make sure and it is why I asked the question the other day (and included about the point of is it okay/appropriate to answer your own question). Re: point 3; I think I understand the point about confounding the markup, thanks for the workaround idea - I could also do a screen grab and paste that in. Re: point 4, understood I will check the reputation required. If I can't do that I'll need to go and figure out how to post an image on the web to link to. Thanks.

Comment: One further thing, re: point 4 above and where you mention embedded images, if I paste an image in of the chart, is there any specific markup language I need to put around it or can I just edit/copy, edit/paste so to speak? I just tried to edit my original question to add the chart in and couldn't get this to work so I canceled the edit and thought I should ask. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes there's markup language, but it won't work for you yet.  (This is a spam prevention mechanism.)  Just insert the URL as text so people can find it.  For more help, use the markup controls while you're editing and also investigate the "help" link that appears in editing mode.

Comment: Re #2, wouldn't it be best to update your question, or am I misunderstanding you? It sounds like you are suggesting the OP provide a faux-answer w/ pasted data to respond to something (a comment or question). I sometimes see that & I always leave a comment chastising them not to.

Comment: @gung I apologize for not being clearer: I have interpreted the question as stating that the OP has *a valid reply* to their own question.  Assuming this, in keeping with site guidelines, I have recommended posting that reply.

Comment: I guess I misread the question. I gather you're keying in on "I think I may have partly solved my own query" right at the beginning. That makes sense. From there the question goes on to discuss adding data in response to comments, so I guess I forgot about the first part.